# Allow child to overflow parent without parent changing size

Tags: html, css, position, overflow

I am trying to create a chrome extension that adds some search features to a website. I am having issues with displaying the content of search results. I would the like the search results to be able to overflow the bottom of the popup container, without the popup changing its height to accomodate the overflow.

My popup is a simple React component that returns:

```
popup.tsx

  return <>{onValidPage ? <SearchPage games={gameData} /> : <InvalidPage />}</>;
```

It only has the CSS styles:

```
popup.css

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

`searchpage.tsx` is another component that renders the search bar I am having difficulty with:

```
searchpage.tsx

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header />

      <SearchBar
        games={games}
        type="referee1"
        placeHolder="Referee #1"
      />

      <div className="radio-button-container">
        <RadioButton
          text="Highlight"
          tooltipText="Highlight games that match your search"
          checked={query.matches === "Highlight"}
          onChange={() => handleMatchChange("Highlight")}
        />

        <RadioButton
          text="Display"
          tooltipText="Only display games that match your search"
          checked={query.matches === "Display"}
          onChange={() => handleMatchChange("Display")}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

The container has the following styles:

```
searchpage.css

  .container {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

Lastly is the actual searchbar component:

```
searchbar.tsx

  return (
    <div className="search-wrapper">
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => onChangeHandler(e.target.value)}
        value={text}
        placeholder={placeHolder}
        className="search"
      />

      {suggestions.length > 0 && (
        <div className="suggestions-container">
          {suggestions.map((suggestion, i) => (
            <div
              key={i}
              className="suggestion"
            >
              {suggestion}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

And the corresponding css:

```
searchbar.css

.search-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 380px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.search {
  appearance: auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  padding: 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: rgb(73, 80, 87);
  cursor: text;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 22px;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out,
    border-width 0.15s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  outline: none;
}

.suggestions-container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: none;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 20;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 140px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.suggestion {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  z-index: 9999;

  &:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  &:hover {
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
  }
}
```

In the pictures, you can see that the entire height of the popup grows in size, rather than just letting the search results flow out of it. How can I fix this?[image]
[image]

I have tried numerous different overflow-y values, setting the max-height of the container and popup, changes z-indexes, and tried various position arguments. None have resulted in the overflow behaviour I am looking for.